# GitHub Pages config variable not returned

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I'm using `{% include some_file.ext %}` to pull stuff from `_includes`-folder for a ***Jekyll*** powered GitHub page/`gh-pages`-branch.

All the includes, like the `header.html`, etc. work perfectly fine. But pulling in other stuff like the `css/js` files (which are included from inside `all.*` files from exact same folder), doesn't work out. And the pathes for the files, which are set using `{{ site.baseurl }}` simply stay empty.

Dumping the variable as well doesn't output anything. It looks like the `{{}}` variables aren't accessible while everything else works just fine. In other words adding the following to the `index.html` returns nothing than the empty tags:

```
<pre>{{ site }}</pre>
```

---

The (locally working) `all.css` file.

```
---
---
{% include css/grid.css %}
{% include css/style.css %}
```

Location of the `all.css` (and `all.js`) file(s):

```
~/root
├── /_includes
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── grid.css
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── analytics.js
│   │   └── general.js
│   └── head.html
├── index.html
├── all.js
└── all.css
```

Comment: assumed in your css you have <style> tags then? i think your css needs to be in the _include folder too.

Comment: @TheCellarRoom I made an update to show the current location of the js and css files. So no, they're added via `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/all.css">` right in the `head.html`, which gets included. Point is that even in the default `index.html`, no variable works out - see above `{{ site }}` (and all others).

Comment: **Update** - I can confirm that the problem is the same when I use `jekyll build --safe` locally. Now: How would I debug that?

Comment: I'm doing exactly this without a problem! Are you sure the page build isn't failing on something else, thus not displaying your changes?

Comment: @AdamB Good question. Dunno, as it's 1 1/2 years later. [Take a look at the never finished repo](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Dynamic-Image-Resize/tree/gh-pages).

Answer (score 0):

if it's any help. I'm running a blog on github pages and we use index.md. I do all my `{{ var }}` stuff in `_layouts/index.html`